# How to send request with android volley basic auth?

Tags: android, header, android-volley, basic-authentication

i want to send a request with basic auth.

My header

> ```
> Username       :        EBA
> Token          :       34242353453456563DSFS
> ```

**And my gsonRequestClass like this :**

```
public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> responseClass,
                       Map<String, String> parameters, Map<String, String> headers, Listener<T> listener,
                       ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mResponseClass = responseClass;
        this.mParameters = parameters;
        this.mHeaders = headers;
    }

    /**
     * Header getter method
     *
     * @return
     * @throws AuthFailureError
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return mHeaders != null ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }
```

Any advice or sample code please ?

Comment: use Retrofit its simple to use refer this [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header)

Comment: how can i do this with volley ?

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to authenticate a `token` the api providers like `google`, `yahoo`, `facebook`, `twitter` .. `etc` `etc` provides code samples for all of the `server-side languages like PHP, JAVA`, etc etc and you are not required to use volley.

But as you have asked question on volley and i have been developed so many android apps using volley, i am starting answer to the `volley` :

---

I am assuming..

1. You have linked the volley jar dependency successfully.
2. You have your web server set up and running
3. You want to login to your own server with these credentials Username : EBA and password : 34242353453456563DSFS
4. And you want a response for this login request or want to get some data as reply to this request.

Here we go...

---

Java code to make a http request to a server page :

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://www.yourserver.com/get_auth.php", 
new Response.Listener<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response)
    {
        serverResponse = response;

        // get response string here; if successful

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
},
new Response.ErrorListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
    {
        serverResponse = error.toString();

        // If request could not be placed then error report here

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
})

{
@Override
protected Map<String,String> getParams()
{
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Username",FirstLast);
    params.put("Token",EmailField.getText().toString());
    return params;
}};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

If you have success in importing library... above code will just need to auto insert library by placing cursor over below two lines and use OPT + RETURN on mac; which will import and include necessary packages for your above request.

---

On your web server get_auth.php should be like :

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    $UserInput = $_POST['Username'];
    $UserId = $_POST['Token'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id4859061_instapromo", "sandhya12345","id4859061_instapromo");

    if (!$con)
    {
        echo "EXCEPTION_CODE_1";
        exit();
    }

    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE `DEVID` = '$UserId' AND `KEYGEN` = '$UserInput'");

    if (!$result)
    {
        echo "EXCEPTION_CODE_2";
        exit();
    }
    if ($result->num_rows == 0)
    {
        echo "FAILURE";
        exit();
    }
    if ($result->num_rows == 1)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $TempThisDate = $row["VALUEDATE"];

        $InstDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$TempThisDate);
        $InstallDate = $InstDate->format('d-m-Y');

        $Response = "SUCCESS#".$InstallDate;
        echo $Response;
        exit();
    }
    if ($result->num_rows > 1)
    {
        echo "REDUNDANT_RECORDS_FOUND";
        exit();
    }

}
else
{
   echo "EXCEPTION_CODE_3";
}
```

In this way from web-server you have to echo / json your data back to requesting app

---

> Java code already `toasts` this server response sent from PHP page. This is a basic working and step by step example.. I hope you or someone else find this useful.

Comment: just keep your web users login LOGIC different from this.. For web users you have to implement SESSION.. Keep this code in separate file and no SESSION REQUIRED in this case. Just send credentials, get it there, if found in users table then return your data from there, accept here in request and then use it in app.

Comment: Username       :        EBA
Token          :       34242353453456563DSFS

these are my header that use for auth, not parameter

Comment: What are these 'Username' and 'token' you are using for...?

Comment: Which API authentication you are trying for? Have you gone through the answer..? It also tells about OAuth

Comment: I'm using basic auth

Comment: @SwiftyIso, I am sorry to downvote as you are not providing the the details very neatly and you are replying so poorly with very few details which does not have any meaning